# Show path homotopy classes not equal?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have some questions I am stuck on. They were left as proof exercises so feel they should be simple, but I don’t know how to show them.

Let $X$ be the one-point union of two copies of $S^1$, connected by a basepoint $x_0$. Let two loops $a$ and $b$ start and end at $x_0$, so that $a$ travels anti-clockwise around one copy of $S^1$, and $b$ the other.
I am wondering how to show that:

a) $[a] \neq e$ and $[b] \neq e$, where $e=[\epsilon]$, $\epsilon$ being the constant map which sends all of $X$ to $x_0$,

and

b) if $[a]^m = [b]^n$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $m=n=0$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are maps $S^1 \rightarrow X$ correct? Do you mean that $\epsilon$ is a map $S^1 \rightarrow X$ aswell? Otherwise your question doesn't make sense. If this is indeed what you mean try and have a look at Van Kampens theorem, you can compute the fundamental group of a wedge of nice enough spaces (locally contractible and path connected which $S^1$ is) easily with the help of that theorem.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is a map $X \rightarrow x_0$, $a$ and $b$ are loops, so paths which are maps $I \rightarrow X$ st $a(0)=b(0)=a(1)=b(1)=x_0$

Comment: But you can only talk about homotopies of maps that have the same domain and codomain, what is the definition of a homotopy between $X \rightarrow X$ and $S^1 \rightarrow X$?